# Python doesn't seem to remember installed packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, pip, distutils

Alright, I have begun messing with Python packaging but I have encountered some problems. I have used `python setup.py install` to install my package, then distribute, and then pip. The packages work for a little while, but then Python eventually stops being able to find them. The interesting thing is that this happens in the same Windows 7 Command Prompt window that I originally gave the action in. I have opened the interactive prompt and tried importing both distribute and then my package. It couldn't find distribute, but found my package, though I have no idea where it is. What  is going on?

UPDATE: I've found the package files where they belong in my Python install. Now how do I get them to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually fixed this. I have to use `python -m <package name>`. It was working that one time because I was within the extracted source code. Whoops.